# WebEx Bypass HTTPS Scanning on a Sophos UTM

Tags: firewall, network-access

I'm running `Sophos UTM 9` with decrypt and scan `HTTPS` traffic enabled.

`WebEx` works fine when I turn off `SSL Scanning` for a machine, but I'm having trouble find all the URLs that `WebEx` uses; so that I can exclude them from the `SSL Scanning`.

Below are all the URLs that I have found within the `Web Filtering` logs.

```
^.*\.webex\.com
^.*\.webexconnect\.com
^.*\.ciscowebex\.com
https://webex.tt.omtrdc.net/
```

I have created a rule to exclude these URLs from the `SSL Scanning` but `WebEx` still doesn't work. I can't see anymore URL present in the logs or see anything being block in the `Firewall`,`Application Control` or `Intrusion Prevention System` logs.

Have I missed something here? Has anyone else got `WebEx` working through a `Sophos UTM` with `HTTPS Decrypt and Scan` enabled?

Comment: Are you able to pull up the logs of what websites were accessed when users report the problem? That might help in narrowing down the list of websites to exclude.

Comment: This is a question only WebEx can answer. (and that answer will very likely not be static.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution after using a packet sniffer on the `WebEx` application.

I was able to obtain all the subnet that `WebEx` is using and exclude them from the SSL Scanning using the following expressions.

```
https:\/\/62\.109\.204\.[0-9]{1,3}
https:\/\/62\.109\.224\.[0-9]{1,3}
https:\/\/62\.109\.230\.[0-9]{1,3}
https:\/\/62\.109\.231\.[0-9]{1,3}
https:\/\/62\.109\.232\.[0-9]{1,3}
https:\/\/62\.109\.234\.[0-9]{1,3}
```